# JSON request not working: Cross origin request not supported on file:// URL

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to prepare a request. But, it is not working. What did I do wrong? I have given the JSON with the proper JSON file extension. Unfortunately, it is not working.

The console shows the following error:

```
training.html:218 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/lil/Desktop/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

```js
"events": [
 { "location": "San Francisco, CA", "date": "May 1", "map": "http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/img/map-ca.png"},
 { "location": "Austin, TX", "date": "May 15", "map": "http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/img/map-ny.png"}, 
 { "location": "New York", "date": "May 31", "map": "http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/img/map-tx.png"}
]

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onload = function() {                     
    if(xhr.status === 200){
        responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var newContent = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.events.length; i++) { 
            newContent += '<div class="event">';
            newContent += '<img src="' + responseObject.events[i].map + '" ';
            newContent += 'alt="' + responseObject.events[i].location + '" />';
            newContent += '<p><b>' + responseObject.events[i].location + '</b><br>';
            newContent += responseObject.events[i].date + '</p>';
            newContent += '</div>';
        }

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);       
xhr.send(null);
```

```html
<body>
    <header><h1>The Maker Bus</h1></header>
    <h2>The bus stops here</h2>
    <section id="content"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to define "not working".

Comment: training.html:218 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/chiho/Desktop/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: The error is crystal, you can't do ajax on a `file://` protocol, you'll need a webserver, for instance WAMP, XAMPP,  EasyPHP etc.

Comment: @adeneo or the much simpler npm http-server

Comment: @Phil - I'd assume that for most people, installing Node, using the command line, getting NPM packages, learning Express etc. is a lot harder than flicking a button on a windows 'puter and having WAMP installed in two seconds, and running automatically ?

Comment: @adeneo you think? Node is very easy to install. From there it's just `npm install -g http-server` and `http-server`

Comment: @Phil - no, WAMP, XAMPP or any of those are easy to install, they come with a windows-installer, and you click a button, and it works. Node is easy when you get the hang of it, but you're lying if you're saying you were up and running with Node within 15 minutes the first time you tried it. By the time you had a webserver running Express and was doing ajax calls, it probably took you quite a few hours. Add to that, most shared webhosting available to new developers at resonable prices is still running on a LAMP stack. If the OP **want's** to spend hours learning Node though, it's great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To work with data in JSON you need to run a local web server in your development environment, here's the most famous:

**Windows:**

Wampp (http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Xampp Recommended ( https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html)

**MAC OS X:**

MAMP ( https://www.mamp.info/en/ )

Alternative options ( my favorite also ) run your cli and install node and http-server

1. brew install node
2. npm install http-server
3. run "http-server" in your json folder
4. Open Localhost:8080 in your favorite browser ( usually the default port is 8080)

Comment: For client-side work, I wouldn't use Apache (with PHP). Node's http-server / Express are all you need.

Comment: Like I said, my favorite option =P 
Thanks for your comment Phil

Comment: FYI, it looks like OP is using Windows so I wouldn't recommend using Homebrew to install node.js

Comment: Thanks! Got this problem solved. Have already downloaded XAMMP and put the json extension file into htcdocs file of XAMMP. Do not forget to add  "http://localhost" before the file name. In my case http://localhost/data.json. Change ---> xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);  to --> xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/data.json', true);  and it works!